# vlc freezes in html when video ends

Tags: html, video, vlc

The vlc video player freezes after the video is finished playing when using the html code below. If loop="yes" is set, the video repeats as is should. But I want the video to play automatically once then stop and reset so that it can be played again. Instead vlc freezes and the vlc area in the browser does not updata.  How do I fix this?

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
  pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
  version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" id="vlc" target="booya40m20m.avi"
  height="1000" width="1000"> <br>
```